# Weird behaviour of function with malloc() and realloc() resulting in Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, realloc

I have a function named `num_to_binary`, which is used to convert a decimal number stored in the form of array. The prototype for this function `num_to_binary` is as below:

`void num_to_binary(int *number_b, int size_of_number);`

Here:

`number_b` is pointer to array which stores my number. For example, if I would like to convert the number 12345 to binary, then I will be storing 12345 in `number_b` as follows:

```
number_b[0] = 1
number_b[1] = 2
number_b[2] = 3
number_b[3] = 4
number_b[4] = 5
```

Also, `size_of_number` is the number of digits in the number (or it is the number of elements in the array `number_b`). So for the number 12345, `size_of_number` has the value 5.

Below is the full declaration of the function `num_to_binary`:

```
void num_to_binary(int *number_b, int size_of_number)
{
    int *tmp_pointer = malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
    int curr_size = 1;
    int i = 0;
    while(!is_zero(number_b,size_of_number))
    {
        if(i != 0)
        {
            curr_size += 1;
            tmp_pointer = realloc(tmp_pointer, curr_size * sizeof(int));
        }
        if(number_b[size_of_number - 1] % 2 == 1)
        {
            tmp_pointer[i] = 1;
            divide_by_2(number_b,size_of_number);
            i = i + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp_pointer[i] = 0;
            divide_by_2(number_b,size_of_number);
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
    int *fin_ans;
    fin_ans = malloc(curr_size * sizeof(int));
    for(int j = 0 ; j < curr_size; j++)
    {
        fin_ans[curr_size-1-j] = tmp_pointer[j];
    }
}
```

In the above function:

`tmp_pointer`: It is initially allocated some memory using `malloc()`, and is used to store the reverse of the binary representation of the number stored in `number_b`

`curr_size`: It stores the current size of `tmp_pointer`. It is initially set to 1.
`i`: It is used to keep track of the `while` loop. It is also used to reallocation purpose, which I have explained a bit later.

`is_zero(number_b, size_of_number)`: It is a function, which returns `1` if the number stored in `number_b` is 0, else it returns 1.

`divide_by_2(number_b, size_of_number)`: It divides the number stored in `number_b` by 2. It does NOT change the size of the array `number_b`.

`fin_ans`: It is an integer pointer. Since the binary representation stored in the array `tmp_pointer` will be the reverse of the actual binary representation of the number, so `fin_ans` will store the correct binary representation of number by reversing the content of `tmp_pointer`.

Below is the how this function works :

1. First of all, `tmp_pointer` is allocated a memory equal to the
   size of 1 int. So, now `tmp_pointer` can store an integer.
2. We now go into the `while` loop. The loop will terminate only
   when the number stored in `number_b` equals 0.
3. Now, we check if `i` is equal to 0 or not. If it is not equal to
   zero, then this means than the loops has been run atleast once, and
   in order to store the next binary digit, we resize the memory
   allocated to `tmp_pointer` so that it can store the next bit.
4. If the last digit of the number is odd, then that implies that the
   corresponding binary digit will be 1, else it will be 0. The
   `if` and `else` condition do this task. They also increment
   `i` each time one of them is executed, and also divide the number by 2.
5. Now, we are out of the loop. It's time to reverse the binary number
   stored in `tmp_pointer` to get the final answer.
6. For this, we create a new pointer called `fin_ans`, and allocate
   it the memory which will be used for storing the correct binary
   representation of the number.
7. The last `for` loop is used to reverse the binary representation
   and store the correct binary representation in `fin_ans`.

The problem:

The code runs for small numbers such as 123, but for large numbers such as 1234567891, it gives a segmentation fault error. This can be checked by trying to print the digits stored in `fin_ans`.

I tried using GDB Debugger, and got to know that the reason for Segmentation Fault lies in the `while` loop. I am sure that the functions `divide_by_2` and `is_zero` are not the reason for Segmentation Fault, since I have tested them thoroughly.

I also used DrMemory, which indicated that I am trying to access (read or write) a memory location which has not been allocated. Unfortunately, I am not able to figure out where the error lies.

I suspect `realloc()` to be the cause of Segmentation Fault, but I am not sure.

Apologies for such a long question, however, I would highly appreciate any help provided to me for this code.

Thanks in advance for helping me out !

Comment: The starting numbers are strings, but they are converted to number by looping through each character of the string, then converting each character to its corresponding digit, and finally storing each digit in the array number_b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- you do not check for memory allocation failure
- you forget to free `tmp_pointer` before leaving the function.
- you allocate a new array `fin_ans` to reserve the array `tmp_pointer` and perform the reverse operation but you do not return this array to the caller, nor do you have a way to return its size. You should change the prototype to return this information.
- if the number of zero, the converted number should probably have 1 digit initialized as 0, but you use `malloc` which does not initialize the array it allocates so `tmp_pointer[0]` is uninitialized.
- you did not provide the code for `is_zero()` nor `divide_by_two()`. It is possible that bugs in these functions cause the segmentation fault, especially if the loop does not reach zero and memory is eventually exhausted during this infinite loop.

Here is a modified version:

```c
int *num_to_binary(int *number_b, int size_of_number, int *binary_size) {
    int i, j, curr_size;
    int *p, *newp;

    curr_size = 1;
    p = malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
    if (p == NULL)
        return NULL;
    p[0] = 0;

    for (i = 0; !is_zero(number_b, size_of_number); i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
            curr_size += 1;
            newp = realloc(p, curr_size * sizeof(int));
            if (newp == NULL) {
                free(p);
                return NULL;
            }
            p = newp;
        }
        p[i] = number_b[size_of_number - 1] % 2;
        divide_by_2(number_b, size_of_number);
    }
    for (i = 0, j = curr_size; i < j; i++)
        int digit = p[--j];
        p[j] = p[i];
        p[i] = digit;
    }
    *binary_size = curr_size;
    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for multiple memory reallocations. Result memory buffer size could be easily evaluated as binary logarithm of the decimal input value. Calculation of the number binary representation could also be simplified:

```
//Transform binary array to actual number
int arr2int(int* pIntArray, unsigned int nSizeIn) {
    if (!pIntArray || !nSizeIn)
        return 0;

    int nResult = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nSizeIn; ++i)
        nResult += pIntArray[i] * (int)pow(10, nSizeIn - i - 1);

    return nResult;
}

int* int2bin(int* pIntArray, unsigned int nSizeIn, unsigned int* nSizeOut){
    //0) Converting int array to the actual value
    int nVal = arr2int(pIntArray, nSizeIn);

    //1)Evaluating size of result array and allocating memory
    if(!nVal)
        *nSizeOut = 1;
    else
        *nSizeOut = (int)floor(log2(nVal)) + 1;

    //2)Allocate and init memory
    int* pResult = malloc(*nSizeOut);
    memset(pResult, 0, *nSizeOut * sizeof(int));

    //3) Evaluate binary representation
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < *nSizeOut; ++i){
        int nBinDigit = (int)pow(2, i);
        if (nBinDigit == (nVal & nBinDigit))
            pResult[*nSizeOut - i - 1] = 1;
    }

    return pResult;
}
```

Testing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define _DC 9

int main()
{
    int test[_DC];
    for (int i = 0; i < _DC; ++i)
        test[i] = i;

    unsigned int nRes = 0;
    int* pRes = int2bin(test, _DC, &nRes);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nRes; ++i)
        printf("%d", pRes[i]);

    free(pRes);
    return 0;
}
```